# Can I use a UK Crunchyroll account on a US PS4 and viceversa?

Tags: crunchyroll

I am planing to start an account on Crunchyroll, but I have some questions and was hoping if someone could help regarding US and UK accounts.

Does it matter if should use an US account or an UK account? Is there any difference between them, in terms of availability and selection?

If I start a US account, would I still be able to use outside US (i.e. overseas)? I live in Europe, but currently I use an US PSN account on my PS4.

Answer (score 2):

Crunchyroll doesn't have regional accounts, they determine what you can watch depending on your current location. *Example: you register in the US, then move to - dunno - Azerbaijan, you'll only be able to watch the shows available in Azerbaijan.* [Source](http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-1018937/region-change#57510885)

Crunchyroll also doesn't care about what kind of device is used with what kind of regional PS/Xbox/whatever account to watch their streams. Again, they only care about your current location.